# parcel not rebuild on changes

Tags: parceljs, parcel

I'm using the parcel with web components and after the application starts, when I change the html of some component it doesn't rebuild, for example I change a div tag to p, in the browser it still remains as a div

Comment: Maybe ur affected by this known issue https://parceljs.org/features/development/#known-issues-with-file-watching

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.